# Can we manipulate a small black hole?

Tags: science-based, physics, black-holes

Imagine lasers (not yet invented) shoot gamma rays onto one single point and creates a kugelblitz (in german lightning ball), a small black hole that can last for a year let's say. Please don't ask or talk about the creation of the kugelblitz and it's lifespan.

I'm wondering... how could we manipulate in a labatory for example. It will fall to earth because of gravity.

We can manipulate antimatter thanks t an electromagnetic field thanks to it's electric charge. But black holes don't have an electric charge (maybe I am wrong about that so please tell me if it's so).

So how can we manipulate a black hole (I'm hoping a theoretically possible answer, and not to sci-fi, possible)

Thank you very much, I need a very complete answer and your help!

Comment: black holes can have charge.

Comment: This question would be better asked in the Physics group

Comment: Creating a kugelblitz is really hard, doing it on the surface of the earth without destroying Earth in the process would be much more challenging.

Comment: For reference, a black hole mass of 1.56e8 kg will have a lifetime of 31.8 million seconds (a little over 1 year), a Schwartchild radius of 2.32e-19 meters, and a temperature of 7.87e14 Kelvin. The Washington Monument is about 0.746e8 kg, so the black hole is about 2.12 W.M. worth of mass.

Answer (score 2):

Black holes can have an electrical charge. For a classical black hole (ignoring quantum effects) the black hole is characterised by only three quantities, its mass, its angular momentum and its electric charge. The angular momentum isn't much use but you can use the charge to apply a force to the black hole.

Your problem is going to be getting a high enough charge to mass ratio to be of any use. You can fire electrons into the black hole to charge it, but the increasing charge will quickly start repelling the extra electrons and make it hard to charge the black hole further. Remember that everyday mass black holes are extraordinarily small so they make for a difficult target when you're trying to shoot electrons into them. The increasing charge will tend to deflect the incoming electrons into hyperbolic orbits so they miss the event horizon. In principle it can be done, but in practice we aren't going to be doing it any time soon.